# Spring, Spring-MVC : Migrate XML configuration to Java giving data source not found error

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, migration

I am working on migrating Spring-MVC XML configuration to Java configuration. We have a lot of configuration such as locale, cache, multi-part, spring-security which is using XML. As of now Spring-security configuration is not required to be in Java, but mainly root-context.xml and servlet-context.xml. After going through other users configuration, I have added some configuration on my own, but having some issues during migration.

One main issue is we are using 2 sessionFactory instances in XML configuration, each for a specific purpose, which are referred in DAO layer. I would like to maintain that in Java configuration as well. Thank you.

Error :

```
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:704)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
```

WebConfig.java :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ourapp.spring"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableCaching
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    }


    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    }

    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource(){
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("../resources/locale/messages.properties");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeInterceptor(){
        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter() {
        return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("../webapp/WEB-INF/views/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public DoNotTruncateMyUrls doNotTruncate(){
       return new DoNotTruncateMyUrls();
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getNormalDataSource(){
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:PORT/DB_NAME");
        config.setUsername("USERNAME");
        config.setPassword("PASSWORD");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory_origin")
    public DataSource getSecondaryDataSource(){
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:PORT/DB_NAME");
        config.setUsername("USERNAME");
        config.setPassword("PASSWORD");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

}
```

AppInitializer.java :

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new
                AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(WebConfig.class);
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        context.setServletContext(container);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher",
                new DispatcherServlet(context));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("*.");
    }
}
```

root-context.xml :

```
<beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory_extended"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="extended_transactions_data_source"/>
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ourapp.spring.model"/>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.USERNAMEQL9Dialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="cache.use_query_cache">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="show_sql">false</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="connection.release_mode">after_statement</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>-->


     <!-- <beans:bean id="extended_transactions_data_source" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource"  destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="dataSourceClassName" value="org.USERNAMEql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"/>
        <beans:property name="maximumPoolSize" value="5" />
        <beans:property name="maxLifetime" value="0" />
        <beans:property name="idleTimeout" value="0" />
        <beans:property name="connectionTimeout" value="0"/>
        <beans:property name="dataSourceProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="url">jdbc:USERNAMEql://localhost:5432/DB_NAME</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="user">USERNAME</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="password">PASSWORD</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager_extended"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager_extended" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory_extended"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory_extended" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="extended_transactions_data_source" />
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ourapp.spring.model"/>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.USERNAMEQL9Dialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="cache.use_query_cache">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="show_sql">false</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="connection.release_mode">after_statement</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>-->
```

Example DAOImpl :

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class RepliesDAOImpl implements RepliesDAO {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "sessionFactory_origin")
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "sessionFactory_extended")
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory_extended;
    @Autowired
    public RepliesDAOImpl(@Qualifier("sessionFactory_origin") SessionFactory sessionFactory, @Qualifier("sessionFactory_extended") SessionFactory sessionFactory_extended) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        this.sessionFactory_extended = sessionFactory_extended;
    }
//Methods in the class
}
```

I have also added entire configs in Pastebin [root-context.xml](https://pastebin.com/WW4THY6E)

[servlet-context.xml](https://pastebin.com/k3tJJxuA)

*Update replies DAOImpl*

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class RepliesDAOImpl implements RepliesDAO {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean()
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory_origin")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[] { "com.ourapp.spring" });
        return sessionFactory;
    }


 @Override
    public Long addReply(Replies replies, int conversationId, Person person) {
        SessionFactory sessi = (SessionFactory) sessionFactory();
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "sessionFactory_origin")
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "sessionFactory_extended")
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory_extended;
    @Autowired
    public RepliesDAOImpl(@Qualifier("sessionFactory_origin") SessionFactory sessionFactory, @Qualifier("sessionFactory_extended") SessionFactory sessionFactory_extended) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        this.sessionFactory_extended = sessionFactory_extended;
    }
```

*Updated webconfig*

```
@Bean(name = "sessionFactory_origin")
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    public DataSource getNormalDataSource(){
   // Bean definition
}

 @Qualifier("extended_data_source")
    @Bean(name ="extended_dataSource" )
    public DataSource getSecondaryDataSource(){
//Secondary data source
}
```

Comment: I didn't think anyone was still using XML configuration for Spring anymore.  I would recommend learning Spring Boot and annotations.

Comment: @duffymo : There are many that do. Do you have any idea whats the problem with my current config. Thank you.

Comment: I'd like to see some data to support your assertion.  Yes, Spring is telling you what's wrong: There's no bean with alias "dataSource".  Try adding that name to the annotation for getNormalDataSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `@Qualifier(value = "sessionFactory_extended")` while creating your bean `getNormalDataSource`

You need to provide a custom qualifier so that spring is able to distinguish between two data sources

If you are using Spring 4.something or '>' version you can add a qualifier while creating beans and while injecting them as follows:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("<some-value-1>")
public DataSource getNormalDataSource(){
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:PORT/DB_NAME");
        config.setUsername("USERNAME");
        config.setPassword("PASSWORD");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }



@Bean(name = "sessionFactory_origin")
@Qualifier("<some-value-2>")
public DataSource getSecondaryDataSource(){
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:PORT/DB_NAME");
        config.setUsername("USERNAME");
        config.setPassword("PASSWORD");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }
```

While injecting you got to specify the qualifier as well

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("<some-value-1>") private DataSource dataSource;
```

You are trying to inject the DataSource into SessionFactory.

The following is the change you need to make:

```
 // If present in same file 

    @Bean()
@Qualifier("sessionFactory_origin")
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
      LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
      sessionFactory.setDataSource(getNormalDataSource());
      sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
        new String[] { "<packages>" });
      //If presenst
      sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

      return sessionFactory;
   }
```

If you are using these beans to be chosen based on the environment. I would suggest you to visit [Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) and [Conditional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) anotations.

Comment: How do I connect the dataSource which is autowired with specific SessionFactory instance? Thank you. I tried what you said, I still get not-found and IDE is not able to find it. Here is how it looks : https://postimg.cc/image/rgw7a8k1p/   2nd :   https://postimg.cc/image/cxp28tyml/

Comment: It will not work, You are trying to wire data source to SessionFactory object. :) Type compatibility.  Spring is not able to find a SessionFactory bean in the app context to inject

Comment: Yes. I agree, but SessionFactory is required in DAO layer. What would you suggest? Thank you.

Comment: You can anyways use the dataSource as it is RepliesDao class. Other way around is to inject the SessinFactory bean itself through injection

Comment: I am sorry I dont understand. DataSource is from javax.sql, not from Hibernate. Can you update your answer so it can work with SessionFactory? Thank you. ]

Comment: I would choose Spring-Profiles if this entire setup is just to configure an env. Since the database name is same in your configuration

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not. I am migrating this for making the application portable, there are various other things we use, which is already migrated.

Comment: @WeareBorg I have updated the same with some more details

Comment: Still no luck. I called the sessionFactory method to get the SesionFactory instance, but the error is still the same.

Comment: What changes have you made ? Post them

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Please check out main post, I have added updated details on bottom of main post. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: @WeareBorg... So you have 3 dataSource objects and none of them has bean id as dataSource and in class RepliesDaoImpl `@Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "sessionFactory_origin")
    private DataSource dataSource;
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173380/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-yates).

Comment: @Autowired works well on the fields you dont need to do constructor injecttions explicitly. Remove constructot for  `RepliesDAOImpl`

Comment: @WeareBorg  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
Accept it If you find the answer and conversation useful

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot for your time and help. :D

Comment: Can you please check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50926837/spring-updated-java-config-showing-directory-listing-instead-of-going-to   . Thanks. :-)